# When to use println in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have added JSR223 PreProcessor in jmeter for one request & language selected is groovy (groovy 2.4.15/groovy scripting engine2.0) , so there i want to print the variable value

and for that i am using log.info but when i am using println to print the value , it is not working.

def x= 25;
log.info x;

so my question is which groovy type it supports in jmeter? because i have gone through most of the links where it was showing println function for printing output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Message is not printing on the console in jmeter using JSR223 and groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805712/message-is-not-printing-on-the-console-in-jmeter-using-jsr223-and-groovy)

Comment: @user7294900 thanks for replying but my concern is i have not much idea about groovy scripting so i wanted learn that and when i used GroovyConsole for practicing then i have found out the syntax used here in groovyConsole & in jmeter is different so i am confused which site to refer for reading.. could you help? Currently using this site- http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.8.9/pdf/wiki-snapshot.pdf

Comment: `println` is a shortcut for [`java.lang.System.out.println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) that prints to a standard output of the java program. Depending on how you launched the jmeter - it's possible that the stdout console window it's not visible for you.

Comment: @daggett can you please refer the sites for learning groovy using jsr223 preprocessor jmeter?